# Rails3 renders a js.erb template with a text/html content-type instead of text/javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, content-type

I'm building a new app with 3.0.0.beta3. I simply try to render a js.erb template to an Ajax request for the following action (in publications_controller.rb):

```
def get_pubmed_data
    entry = Bio::PubMed.query(params[:pmid])# searches PubMed and get entry
    @publication = Bio::MEDLINE.new(entry) # creates Bio::MEDLINE object from entry text
    flash[:warning] = "No publication found."if @publication.title.blank? and @publication.authors.blank? and @publication.journal.blank?      
    respond_to do |format|
        format.js
    end
end
```

Currently, my get_pubmed_data.js.erb template is simply

```
alert('<%= @publication.title %>')
```

The server is responding with the following

```
alert('Evidence for a herpes simplex virus-specific factor controlling the transcription of deoxypyrimidine kinase.')
```

which is perfectly fine except that nothing happen in the browser, probably because the content-type of the response is 'text/html' instead of 'text/javascript' as shown by the response header partially reproduced here:

```
Status 200
Keep-Alive timeout=5, max=100
Connection Keep-Alive
Transfer-Encoding chunked
Content-Type text/html; charset=utf-8
```

Is this a bug or am I missing something? Thanks for your help!

Comment: How do you call `get_pubmed_data`? In Rails 3 you have to do: `<%= link_to 'Click here', :controller => :publications, :action => :get_pubmed_data, :remote => true %>`

Comment: The call to get_pubmed_data is fine, done through a javascript observe_field function, with the right `-Requested-With XMLHttpRequest`request Headers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I finally was able to get the right content-type in the response by forcing it with:

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.js {render :content_type => 'text/javascript'}
end
```

Answer (score 1):

With Rails 3.1.1 I ran into a similar issue. My response would render as html even though I had explicitly mentioned format.js in my controller. It turns out the problem was that I had jquery.js files in my assets and being loaded by the template. jquery-rails uses its own copy of jquery and having these files also loaded caused rails to render the response as html for some reason. Might help someone else stuck with this issue.

Comment: how did you end up fixing this?  i've got the same issue and no matter what order i load it, something is broken.

Answer (score 0):

had a similar problem where the js file would load as a text file, but in the end it was just my scrits which were loading in the wrong order.

replace

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :all %>
```

with

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.min" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery-ui.min" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "rails" %>
```

Also to note, the getscript method

ie replace:

```
onClick="<%= get_pubmed_data_path(:format => :js) %>"
```

with:

```
onClick="$.getScript('<%= escape_javascript(get_pubmed_data_path(:format => :js)) %>');"
```

Comment: Great, I'll try that tomorrow in the first place…

Comment: Well, it didn't work. Still getting my js.erb template embeded in layout.

Comment: the only thing i can see is you might want to upgrade rails (assuming you are still using beta3). With Rails 3.0.0 it works for me. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it turned out that I created a method called content_type on my controller which was overriding the default.