# How to remove application layout from a particualar Ruby on Rails page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, layout, rendering

How can I remove the layout application.html.erb from rendering on a particular page. It is now visible on all pages in my application.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can override default rendering at the controller level.

```
class Admin::HomeController < Admin::BaseController
  layout "admin"
```

You can also override rendering of layouts at a controller action level:

```
def show
  render :layout => "layout_for_show_only"
end
```

And, if you are really desperate, you can override layouts in the view:

```
<%= render "print_view", :layout => "print" %>
```

See the excellent rails guide on the subject: [layouts and rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html)

ian.

Comment: thanks! I did this in the controller..
def show
 render :layout=>false
end

Comment: @Themasterhimself- If you want to remove it from all the pages of the controller, you can do `layout nil` at the top of the controller.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add to the controller:

```
layout false, only: [:show, :edit]
```

which means, that application layout won't be rendered for the show and edit pages

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer.

You can set: format.js {render :layout=>false}

[jQuery + Ajax + Haml. js.erb files not firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412375/rails3-jquery-ajax-haml-js-erb-files-not-firing)